# When declaring a method, what do the various argument prefixes mean?

Tags: ruby

When declaring a method, what do the various prefixes for the arguments mean?

```
sh(*cmd, &block)
```

What does the `*` before `cmd` mean?

What does the `&` before `block` mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asterisk `*` means to combine all of the remaining arguments into a single list named by the argument.  The ampersand `&` means that if a block is given to the method call (i.e. `block_given?` would be true) then store it in a new Proc named by the argument (or *pseudo*-argument, I guess).

```
def foo(*a)
  puts a.inspect
end
foo(:ok) # => [:ok]
foo(1, 2, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]

def bar(&b)
  puts b.inspect
end
bar() # => nil
bar() {|x| x+1} # => #<Proc:0x0000000100352748>
```

Note that the `&` must appear last, if used, and the `*` could be next-to-last before it, or it must be last.

The `*` operator can also be used to "expand" arrays into argument lists at call time (as opposed to "combining" them in a definition), like so:

```
def gah(a, b, c)
  puts "OK: a=#{a}, b=#{b}, c=#{c}"
end
gah(*[1, 2, 3]) # => "OK: a=1, b=2, c=3"
gah(1, *[2, 3]) # => "OK: a=1, b=2, c=3" # must be last arg.
```

Similarly, the `&` operator can be used to "expand" a Proc object as the given block when calling a function:

```
def zap
  yield [1, 2, 3] if block_given?
end
zap() # => nil
zap(&Proc.new{|x|puts x.inspect}) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that explains it perfectly.

Comment: Similarly, `array.each(&proc)` passes the object `proc` as the block argument to the method `#each`.  And if you had an array of command arguments and a block, you could call `sh(*cmd, &block)` to pass in each of the elements in `cmd` as an argument and `block` as the block.

Comment: @maerics Are there any other argument prefixes in Ruby?